# Matlab FTP download files with certain string in name

Tags: string, matlab, ftp

I am trying to download only certain files from a folder. The folder contains thousands of files named:
*z_cams_c_ecmf_20160904000000_prod_fc_sfc_120_duaod550.nc
z_cams_c_ecmf_20160904000000_prod_fc_sfc_120_gtco3.grib
z_cams_c_ecmf_20160904000000_prod_fc_sfc_000_aod550.nc
etc.etc.*

I only want those that end in ***duaod550.nc*** and ***aod550.nc***
Is there a way to isolate this string from the filename? Unfortunately I cannot use the .nc because there are other files that have this extention and I don't need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what you need to do is use the a wildcard in the ftp command in matlab. From the [help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ftp.mget.html)

> mget(ftpobj,contents) retrieves the file or folder specified by contents from an FTP server into the MATLAB® current folder.
>
> contents --
> Character vector enclosed in single quotation marks that specifies either a file name or a folder name. Can include a wildcard character (*).

```
filelist=mget(ftpobj, '*duaod550*')
filelist=mget(ftpobj, '*aod550*')
```